# Using pure javascript to prefill a textbox with a url hash

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox on a web page. I would like to get the value of a URLs hash e.g. 12345 and place it as the value of the textbox **upon loading** the page (if there is a value), otherwise, I would like the textbox to remain blank.

I have tried using this code:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

function onoff(){
// pre-fill chat id textbox
  if(hash){
    var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
    document.getElementById("chat").value = hash_value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("chat").value = '';
  } 
}
```

And in the html code(I am having trouble in calling the function).

```
<input type="text" id="chat" maxlength="5" required="">
```

If I were to change the value of the hash, would it be possible to have this fill the text box on load?

Comment: window.onload=onoff();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing! Just pass your function into `window.onload`:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

window.onload = function onoff(){
// pre-fill chat id textbox
  if(hash){
    var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
    document.getElementById("chat").value = hash_value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("chat").value = '';
  } 
}

<input type="text" id="chat" maxlength="5" required="">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Execute your function on `DOMContentLoaded`. Note that this function can be limited to this:

```
function onoff(){
    document.getElementById("chat").value = window.location.hash.substr(1);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onoff);
```

To also capture pure changes to the hash (in which case the page is not reloaded), also capture the corresponding `hashchange` event:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", onoff);
```